# How to make vitejs compile class private fields to legacy code?

Tags: typescript, vite, ecmascript-2016, es5-compatiblity

I am using `vitejs` and `typescript` and I want to set the compile target to `es2016`, but it seems that, the class private fields aren't be compiled.

```
class Task {
   #prepare() { // here should be compiled.
   }
}
```

I tried to set `build.target` in `vite.config.js` and `compilerOptions.target` in `tsconfig` and it doesn't work.

`@vitejs/plugin-legacy` doesn't transform the code either.